# How do I write RGB values of points selected by roipoly in matlab to a text file?

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I did :

```
I = imread('abc.jpg');
BW = roipoly(I);
```

I am trying to get the pixel value of all the points that I have clicked while creating a polygon.

```
r= BW(:, :, 1 );
g= BW(:, :, 2 );
b= BW(:, :, 3 );
```

This doesn't work.

Finally I would like to write to text file:

```
filename = fullfile('C:\Users\ABC\Documents\MATLAB','test.txt'); 
fid = fopen(filename,'w'); 
fprintf(fid, '%d %d %d', r,g,b);
fclose(fid);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that `size(BW)` is only 2D while `I` is 3D. `BW` is only a binary mask indicating what pixels were selected by `roipoly`.

A possible solution is to use the `BW` mask to select the pixels from `I`:

```
rI = reshape(I,[],3); %// "flatten" the image
selectedRGB = rI(BW,:);  %// select the pixels in the polygon
```

Now you can write to file

```
dlmwrite( fullfile('C:\Users\ABC\Documents\MATLAB','test.txt'), selectedRGB, 'delimiter', ' ');
```

See [`dlmwrite`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dlmwrite.html) for more info.

---

If you are only interested in the RGB values of the polygon's corners (and not the entire area), you can use the following code

```
[BW xi yi] = roipoly(I);
```

Now you should ignore `BW` which represent the area, and work only with `xi` and `yi`:

```
sel = sub2ind( size(I(:,:,1)), yi, xi ); %// convert indices to linear indices
selectedRGB = rI(sel,:); %// will give you the RGB of the corners only.
```

Alternatively, you can use [`ginput`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ginput.html) to select points in image.

Comment: Sir Thanks for answer but the output shown the file "test.txt" is showing RGB values of everything within that region inside polygon. I am trying to get the RGB of the point on which I click. Is there any way to do that. Thanks.

Comment: If you only want to pick points, and not the entire region, you might consider using [`ginput`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ginput.html). Or use `roipoly` with `[BW xi yi] = rooipoly(I);`.

Comment: @Leo BTW, it's not "Sir" - I'm not knighted (yet). But if you insist you can use ["Herr Doctor"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doctor_(title)) ;)

Comment: Alright Herr Doctor :) I am new to matlab so can you help me out what to do after [BW xi yi] = rooipoly(I); because I m getting all junk data in output file do i need to change the above code that you mentioned also. Thanks.

Comment: Its showing error in line "selectedRGB = rI(sel,:);" will we rI or something else here

Comment: use same `rI=reshape(I,[],3);`. @Leo

Comment: Yes I still getting that error " rI = reshape(I,[],3); sel = sub2ind( size(I(:,:,1)), yi, xi ); selectedRGB = rI(sel,:); " getting error in last line

Comment: it just says "Error in project>pushbutton26_Callback (line 381)
selectedRGB = rI(sel,:); %// will give you the RGB of the corners only."

Comment: @Leo can you try [`getlasterror`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/lasterror.html) to get a more specific error? aletrnatively, can you run in debug mode and place a breakpoint at the problematic line?

Comment: I got this "message: 'Error while evaluating UIControl Callback'
    identifier: 'MATLAB:badsubscript'
         stack: [0x1 struct]"

Answer (score 0):

This code creates points in the corners of the polygon using pixel coordinates,
creats the mask of the region of interest, uses the BW mask to create a grayscale image of the region and then the grayscale region is converted back to RGB.
The text file created in the end of the code contains the Unit8 data of the image.

Is it only the manually specified coordinates all you want to the text file?

```
I = imread('image.jpg'); 


c = [62 95 103 70];  % specify column coordinates (more than 4 if you want)
r = [126 122 193 197]; % specify row coordinates (more than 4 if you want)

BW = roipoly(I,c,r); % convert to binary mask
[R C] = size(BW); 

for i = 1:R
    for j = 1:C
     if BW(i,j) == 1

            outputImage(i,j) = I(i,j); % get grayscale image of the specified region

     else

            outputImage(i,j) = 0; 

     end
    end
end

imtool(outputImage, []); % in imtool you can see that pixels have only one value
rgbBinary = cat(3,outputImage,outputImage,outputImage);  % convert grayscale image to binary rgb
finalImage = im2uint8(rgbBinary); % convert image from double binary rgb (0 1) to unit8 256 value rgb
imtool(finalImage) % analyze image using (Inspect pixel values)

for i = 1:R
    for j = 1:C
     if BW(i,j) == 1
            finalImage(i,j,1)=I(i,j,1);
            finalImage(i,j,2)=I(i,j,2);
            finalImage(i,j,3)=I(i,j,3);
     end
    end
end

imshow(finalImage) % the specified area in rgb


txtdoc = fopen( 'imageData.txt', 'wt' ); % creates txt file if it doesn't exist or overwrites the existing file

  dlmwrite('imageData.txt',finalImage,'delimiter',' ') % writes the data to txt file delimited by space

fclose(txtdoc);
```

Comment: Please add some descriptions responding to the  specific  topics in the question